# Sorting data by range of numbers

Tags: excel, sorting, numbers, range

I recieve table of data sorted by purchase order PO number in asc.
For further analysis of data, I'm supposed to sort it out by business directions (sectors or departments e.g.). There is a range of order numbers, each of them related to particular direction, like 1000-1999 direction A, 2000-2999 direction B.
Ideally, I need them to be automatically sorted in ascending order with additional sum row underneath and direction name above.
The problem is, that quantity of digits in number is not limited, which means that for some extra orders might be added one digit aside, or even slash and letter, like 2000/A, or 20,000 - and this last one is supposed to be in the range of 2000-2999 POs.

What might be used to solve the problem?

Comment: So do you really only care about the first digit of the field?

Comment: Well, let's put it that way, the first range of PO is from 1 to 99,000, the second is from 100,000 to 199,999 and so on. I care about 6 first digits the most, and the rest of POs with different additions by the end of number might be sorted manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that this will solve your problem.  This fucntion will successively shrink a string from the right until it is a number.  You can enter this function into a vba module and then use it in your spreadsheet.

```
Function getnumber(s As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Len(s) To 0 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Left(s, i)) Then
            getnumber = Left(s, i)
            i = 0
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

If this works, I'm glad.  If it doesn't, you'll need to clarify what you're looking for.

The biggest thing that I would suggest is redefining your input to make this less tedious.